# UIButton placed above a UIImage gets hidden at times in a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uibutton, uicollectionviewcell

I have three `UIButton` over three `UIImageView` placed in a `UICollectionView` and has an action assigned to them. At times, the `UIButton` over `UIImage` gets hidden automatically. How to solve this?

Comment: can post the screenshot of your design and your result ui?

Comment: And also post your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: put tableviewCell design layout screenshot.